# Is it possible to get the isrc of the tracks with Playlist/Tracks in Deezer API

Tags: api, http, deezer

everything is in the title. Is there a way to get the ISRC of all the tracks of a playlist at once (I mean without having to make a track request for each track and hit the request quota) when using the Playlist/tracks endpoint of the Deezer API?
Is there another method to get it done without multiple requests to the track endpoint ?

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, you can not get the ISRC with only one request to the endpoint /playlist/tracks, you have to execute new requests in order to get the information.

Comment: Does this mean it is necessary to do one api request per track that we need the ISRC for?  Is there anyway to get info for multiple tracks using the /track endpoint?

Comment: Yes, you have to do a request on all tracks if you want the ISRC.

Comment: Is the /track endpoint subject to the same rate limit of 10/sec?

Comment: Yes, the quota limit is on all requests